# PyTorch 1.12 on Mac Monterey

Tags: python, pytorch, homebrew, apple-m1, miniconda

I cannot use PyTorch 1.12.1 on macOS 12.6 Monterey with M1 chip.

Tried to install and run from Python 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10 with the same result.

I think that PyTorch was working before I updated macOS to Monterey. And the Rust bindings, tch-rs are still working.

Here is my install and the error messages I get when trying to run.

### Install

```bash
brew install libtorch

python3.9 -m venv venv39

source venv39/bin/activate

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

### Error message

```
python
Python 3.9.14 (main, Sep  6 2022, 23:16:16)
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/Documents/install/Modern_Computer_Vision/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 202, in <module>
    from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
ImportError: dlopen(~/Documents/install/Modern_Computer_Vision/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: (__ZN4c10d11debug_levelEv)
  Referenced from: '@/Documents/install/Modern_Computer_Vision/venv39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.dylib'
  Expected in: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libtorch/1.12.1/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib'
```

### Tried using Miniconda

I had almost the same result.

```
conda create -n conda39 python=3.9 -y
conda activate conda39
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch

❯ python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 01:52:34)
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sami/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 202, in <module>
    from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/sami/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: (__ZN4c10d11debug_levelEv)
  Referenced from: '/Users/sami/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.dylib'
  Expected in: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libtorch/1.12.1/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib'
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend *not* touching your system python installations for your own projects, instead the recommended way is using conda (see [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)). The reason is that each conda environment encapsulates a whole separate python installation that does not interfere (and doesn't get interfered with) with any other programs. This is especially important for C/C++ libraries like the ones pytorch is using.

Comment: Thanks I did use venv but pip based:

```
brew install libtorch

python3.9 -m venv venv39

source venv39/bin/activate

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

Other people have said that pip worked better than conda.
I currently use pip but if conda works better I would install miniconda and try.

Comment: If you use pip you have to install the correct cudatoolkit manually, in a conda environment you can use conda to install it for you (with the command provided on the pytorch page). Even if you use venv, the environment is still using your systems python installation, which is not the case if for conda environments.

Comment: Thanks @flawr but it is a Mac with the M1 chip, so no CUDA only MPS.

Comment: Sure, I'm not sure if pytorch supports an exotic architecture like that one, but the point still hold!

Comment: Thanks @flawr. I followed your advice and used Miniconda for install but had very similar results. I updated the main part with description of this.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when trying to install PyTorch 1.13.

The PyTorch install instruction was not working, but it was due to a conflict between brew and Miniconda. When I uninstalled Miniconda both stable and nightly pip install worked.

```
virtualenv -p /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.14/bin/python3.9 pt113
source pt113/bin/activate

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```